# search outlook mail Item by displayed received date instead of Header Information Date in C#

Tags: email, date, search

I have received an  outlook mail at  25 Jun 2013 14:52:37 -0400 (EDT)
and it is displaying:

```
Wed 6/26/2013 12:29 AM  (in GMT).
```

Now in my C# window application when i am seraching mail item

this mail is not displaying between received date 26 June to 28 June 
(if we are seraching it between received date 25 June to 28 June   it is displaying )
my search condition in 
as follows:

```
"urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived >= '6/26/2013' AND  "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" <='6/28/2013'
```

How to apply my search on Displayed date and time instead of Information in Header information?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is here

```
  using OutLook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; 

    OutLook.Application outlookObj;
     OutLook.NameSpace olintNS; 
    OutLook.MailItem mailitem; 
    mailitem = outlookObj.CreateItem(OutLook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
     OutLook.PropertyAccessor pa = mailitem.PropertyAccessor; 

    DateTime datStartUTC = pa.LocalTimeToUTC(Convert.ToDateTime("6/26/2013"));
     DateTime datEndUTC =pa.LocalTimeToUTC(Convert.ToDateTime("6/28/2013").AddDays(1));
```

// My Search Condition

```
     string filter = @"@SQL=((""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '" + datStartUTC + @"' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" <='" + datEndUTC + @"' ) OR (""urn:schemas:httpmail:date"" >= '" + datStartUTC + @"' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:date"" <='" + datEndUTC + @"' ) ) ";
 OutLook.Items items = oFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);

 // Now I can Put searched item in to My DataTable

foreach (OutLook.MailItem mail in items) 
{ 
DataRow dr = dtInbox.NewRow(); 
dr["TO"] = mail.To; 
dr["From"] = mail.SenderEmailAddress;
dr["Subject"] = mail.Subject;
dr["EntryID"] = mail.EntryID; 
dr["folderStoreID"] = oFolder.StoreID; dr["Date"] = mail.ReceivedTime;//? (mail.SentOn != null ? mail.SentOn.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "") : (mail.ReceivedTime); dtInbox.Rows.Add(dr);
 }
```

---